# GWT. Fire ChangeEvent on ListBox programmatically.

Tags: java, gwt

I want to programmatically fire ListBox's `ChangeEvent`. I found function, but dont understand what type of parameter i need to pass:

```
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(NativeEvent - where???, listBox());
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can fire a native ChangeEvent on a widget using:

```
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createChangeEvent(), yourListBox);
```

Comment: This only fire event and does not change selected item.

Comment: Saeed Zarinfam: set the item forst, then fire the event using Strelok's advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is old question, but I want to share my solution, because it is only one that works for me(gwt.version= 2.6.1  and com.github.jdramaix gwtchosen version = 1.2.0)

```
public class ChosenListBoxNew extends ChosenListBox {
    public ChosenListBoxNew() {
    super();
    }

    public void fireUpdateEvent(){
    ensureChosenHandlers().fireEvent(new ChosenChangeEvent(this.getValue(), this.getSelectedIndex(), null));
    }
}
```

And you can fire update event by calling fireUpdateEvent() of new class:

```
moduleSelectionLst.setSelectedIndex(-1); //Update selected value
moduleSelectionLst.update(); //Update UI
moduleSelectionLst.fireUpdateEvent();  // Fire update event
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fire event using JSNI:

```
public native void fireOnChange(String elementId)/*-{
    var element = $doc.getElementById(elementId);
    if ( element )
        element.onchange();
}-*/;
```